# Simple Form Gem - How to display the name of a model in an association - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to **rails** & I know this may be a very simple question, but I'm unsure how to display the name of a company using 'simple form' association?

- In my schema I've a table `companies` with the columns `name` & `content`
- In my schema I also have a table `users` with the columns `first name`, `last name` & `company_id:integer`
- A `company` `has_many :users`
- A `user` `belongs_to :company`

Everything works perfectly in my views expect the display of the name of my company

in my views:

```
<h2>Sign up Primary Admin</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.association :company, collection: Company.all.order(:name), prompt: "please select your company", label: 'Company' %>
    <%= f.input :firstname, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :lastname, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length) %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "users/shared/links" %>
```

i get the below display:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> label_method => the label method to be applied to the collection to
>   retrieve the label (use this instead of the text_method option in
>   collection_select)

You should define the `label_method` to `name` to display the company names.

```
<%= f.association :company, collection: Company.all.order(:name), prompt: "please select your company", label_method: :name, label: 'Company' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

SimpleForm uses `to_s` method for association labels, so you have to define your own `to_s` method for your `company` model.
i. e:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_s
    name
  end 
end
```